# How do I get ng-file-upload to work with Node?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ng-file-upload

I am using Angular with Node, Express, and Multer and ng-file-upload. For some reason I am getting 400 (bad request) http request error. I tried different things but this is all is coming back. Here is the code sample.

HTML

```
<form  ng-controller="adminController" name="form">
```

Single Image with validations
  Select

submit

Angular app.js

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $log.info($scope.file);


  if (  $scope.file) {
    $scope.upload($scope.file);

  }
};



// upload on file select or drop
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: '/api/admin/photos',
         headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },

        data: {file: file}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};
```

Node js

```
//upload photos
apiRoutes.post('/admin/photos',upload.single(),function(req,res){
    console.log(req);
    res.json({name: 'this works'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upload.single()` should instead be `upload.single('file')` since that is the property name you're using for your upload. Also, explicitly setting:

```
headers : {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
```

is unnecessary.

If that still doesn't work, you should temporarily remove `upload.single('file')` and ensure that your route handler is being reached to begin with (and some prior middleware/route handler hasn't intercepted it).

Comment: ok, ive done this and still no luck... ive even before this tried other things than multer and same results.so I just removed the upload.single from there and same results. How can I test to see what is picking it up?

Comment: Quickest way might be one of: 1. Look for a line that sets the status code to 400; 2. Start eliminating middleware until the route handler is executed; 3. Insert a new middleware that merely logs something to the console and passes execution on (via `next()`) and keep moving it up the chain until you see it log to the console.

Comment: ok great. it seemed to be bodyparser.urlencoded. that is supposed to be used for something else, now I have to figure out why that's causing problems. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Last question...in my node section I am not getting the file. There is no req.file available. Would you know why?

Comment: Did you check the request headers (especially `Content-Type`) and payload format using your browser's web development tools?

Comment: Sorry for being completely new on this. I did a console.log on the server side and do not see any kind of 'file' under request. How do I check in developer tools content-type? What I get in developer tools going out is this.   
Blob {$ngfName: "2014-01-27 21.13.27.jpg"}
$ngfName: "2014-01-27 21.13.27.jpg"
name: "2014-01-27 21.13.27.jpg"
size: 5768
type: "image/jpeg"
__proto__: Blob

Comment: For example, if you're using Chrome, you just click on the Network tab after opening the developer tools (ctrl+shift+I) and then click on the file upload request. From there you can see the headers and body sent to the server.

Comment: payload.....

------WebKitFormBoundaryETSfBAn03ifyj5uc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2014-01-27 21.13.27.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

my headers say this though...i wonder if thats a conflict

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json

Comment: the headers's content-type is application/json when the payload's content-type is image/jpeg..could this be the issue?

Comment: You could try explicitly overriding the `Content-Type` like you were originally doing, but it shouldn't be necessary in most cases.

Comment: Tried that as well. I have an interceptor  used for tokens that has content type as application/json. Tried adding multipart onto it but now getting some boundary error.